# What should do if I want to have multiple input & multiple output in python transform in palantir foundry?

Tags: palantir-foundry

I have scenario where I have multiple inputs and multiple outputs which I want to implement in python `transform`. I know palantir foundry does not support multiple output whereas it supports multiple inputs. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 7):

Use `@transforms` where multiple Inputs and Outputs are supported:

```
from transforms.api import transform, Input, Output

@transform(
    output1=Output(
        "/output1"),
    output2=Output(
        "/output2"),
    input1=Input(
        "/input1"),
    input2=Input("/input2")
)
def transformation(output1, output2,
                   input1, input2):
     df1 = input1.dataframe()
     df2 = input2.dataframe()
     output1.write_dataframe(df1)
     output2.write_dataframe(df2)
```